# Can I download ubuntu on a mac and burn it to a cd for windows 7?

Tags: windows, live-usb, mac, cd

I am looking to download ubuntu on my mac and make a bootable cd or flash drive for a PC with windows 7. how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course possible! Official Ubuntu page itself has a guide on how to achieve this if you're on a Mac OSX. Please refer below guidelines to do so;

- **[How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)**

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

If for CD, just open your CD burner application and then burn the image (.iso) file.

For flash drive, I couldn't help you out, sorry mate.